# Как выбрать наименьшее и наибольшее число в списке, если там есть не только числа?

Tags: python, список, type-error

Мой код:

```
for a in [7, 2, "abc", 10, 4]:
    if largest is None:
        largest = a
    elif smallest is None:
        smallest = a
    elif a > largest:
        largest = a
    elif a < smallest:
        smallest = a
```

**Выдаёт ошибку**:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Как исправить?

Comment: добавьте if isinstance(a, int)

Comment: А есть более простое решение?

Comment: Куда уж проще-то

Comment: Ещё, как вариант, сразу итерироваться по отфильтрованному списку: `for a in filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, int), [7, 2, "abc", 10, 4]):`

Answer (score 1):

**вариант 1:**

```
res_min = min(i for i in [7, 2, "abc", 10, 4] if isinstance(i, int))
```

**вариант 2:**

```
res_min = min(filter(lambda i: isinstance(i, int), [7, 2, "abc", 10, 4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Подлиннее, чем у @Zhihar , но тоже решение:

```
sp=[7, 2, "abc", 10, 4]
sp2=[] #создаём пустой список
[sp2.append(i) for i in sp if type(i)==int] #добавляем в новый список элемент, если его тип - int
print(min(sp2), max(sp2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Всторенные функции `min()` и `max()` могут принимать в качестве параметра ключ. Это можно использовать примерно так (при сравнении строки приравниваем +- бесконечности):

```
f = [7, 2, "abc", 10, 4]

sm = min(f, key=lambda x: x if type(x)==int else float('inf'))
bg = max(f, key=lambda x: x if type(x)==int else -float('inf'))

print(f'{sm = }, {bg = }')  # sm = 2, bg = 10
```